# Warning on dataproc while using partitionBy on a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to write a dataframe contents to google cloud storage using a pyspark on dataproc. Though the write is successful, there are a lot of warning messages in the logs which I have pasted below. Is there some setting that I am missing that I need to while creating the cluster or in the pyspark program ? Or is this some google issue?

**Note**: Data written on the google storage by the dataframe is > 120 GB uncompressed. But I have noticed the same warnings even when I process data which is 1GB in size uncompressed. This is a simple dataframe with 50 columns that are read, some transformations are done and written to disk.

**Dataframe Write statement is like below:**

```
df.write.partitionBy("dt").format('csv').mode("overwrite").options(delimiter="|").save("gs://bucket/tbl/")
```

**Warning statements in the Pyspark logs:**

```
18/04/01 19:58:28 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 182.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 68943, admg-tellrd-w-20.c.syw-analytics-repo-dev.internal, executor 219): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:861)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityGenerator.close(UnivocityGenerator.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CSVFileFormat.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.releaseResources(FileFormatWriter.scala:475)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:450)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask$$anonfun$execute$2.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.AbstractScalaRowIterator.foreach(AbstractScalaRowIterator.scala:26)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$DynamicPartitionWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:432)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:287)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.close(Channels.java:178)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopOutputStream.close(GoogleHadoopOutputStream.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:857)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:358)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: The core error is `Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone { "code" : 500, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Backend Error", "reason" : "backendError" } ], "message" : "Backend Error" }`. That should be a rare/transient error. Are you seeing that consistently?

Comment: Also, you probably want to change that to `df.repartition($"dt").write.partitionBy("dt").format('csv').mode("overwrite").options(delimiter="|").save("gs://bucket/tbl/")` for performance, especially if there are a lot of partitions.

Comment: Hi Karthik, Thank you for the response. How would the repartition help here ? I am splitting 7 years worth of data datewise(which is the ask), hence there will be close to 2300 partitions. Wouldn't the repartition add an overhead, since its internally calling coalesce to reduce the number of files it writes to ? What should the value for $"dt" be in the answer you have suggested above.

Comment: `repartition`, as opposed to `coalesce`, will add a shuffle step that can be expensive for a large number of rows but in some cases it can outweight its cost by making subsequent steps more efficient.
Using `explain` to print out the logical plans might help, too. If you use `repartition($"dt")` the `dt`column will be used as the partitioning key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it was indeed slow -- for me it took over 8 minutes.

I got a significant speedup (down to under 5 minutes) just by using Dataframes rather than RDDs to read the CSV files. This avoids shipping all the data between JVM <-> Python. Here's the code I used:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

schema = schema = StructType([
  StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col4", StringType(), True),
  StructField("col5", StringType(), True)])

schema_df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("delimiter", "|").csv("gs://path/to/incremental_file.txt*")
schema_df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

schema_df2 = spark.read.schema(schema).option("delimiter", "|").csv("gs://path/to/hist-file*.gz")
schema_df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")   

union_fn = schema_df2.union(schema_df)
w = Window.partitionBy("col1","col2").orderBy(col("col4").desc())
union_result = union_fn.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(w)).where(col("row_num") == 1).drop("row_num").drop("col4")
union_result.createOrReplaceTempView("merged_tbl")
schema_merged_tbl = spark.sql("""select col1,col2,col3,col5 as col6 from merged_tbl""")
schema_merged_tbl.write.partitionBy("col6").format('csv').mode("overwrite").options(delimiter='|',codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("hdfs_merge_path")
```

Answer (score 1):

(This is not an answer to the question, but this didn't fit in a comment. It's related to thread on calling `repartition(...)` before `write.partitionBy`).

Without `repartition(...)`, that's going to take forever on GCS. Under the hood, when you say write.partitionBy(...), spark's tasks will each **serially** write one file at a time for each partition. That's already slow on HDFS, but since GCS has higher latency, that's going to be even slower. If it's 500ms to create each file, writing 2300 partition files will take ~20 minutes per task.

If you shuffle the data, you'll introduce another ("reduce") stage of tasks that will end up with all the data for one partition. So instead of writing 2300*previous-stage-task files, you'll just write 2300 files. This is what you want, especially when you have more than a few partitions.

You might want to experiment with the number of partitions that repartition(...) makes (aka reducer tasks). By default it is 200, but you may want to raise that. Each reducer will end up with a subset of the 2300 output partitions, and will serially write each output file. Again, assuming writing one file takes 500ms, 2300/200 = 115 files = ~1 minute per task. If you have more reducers, you'll get more parallelism, so each task will take less time. But you should set the number of reducers based on the number of nodes in your cluster (e.g. 4x the number of vcores).

Also, you might want to raise spark.executor.cores to 4 (`--properties spark.executor.cores=4`), since this will be pretty IO bound.

Comment: i did try the repartition and it wrote to a single file for every date instead of 200 part files. I am also now writing the files to the hdfs on the master node instead of directly the google storage which faster. I did not notice any significant increase in performance time, after this change. Currently each year of my data is 150 GB uncompressed and I have a n1-highmem-64 cluster with 5 nodes. With this configuration and the defaults values which gets assigned while cluster creation,every year is roughly taking 50 minutes to process. Is there any setting im missing to get this done faster ?

Comment: Also this is daily process where i have to read the data, process the updates and then write the data to day wise files. Hence after using the repartition and processing the next days load, its taking forever to write back the hdfs with the repartiton on.

Comment: Do you mind giving me a short repro on a fake dataset? It's hard to help without being able to tweak code. Ignoring Spark, you should be able to copy 150GB pretty fast, even with a single thread on a single core. So 50 minutes is obviously unreasonable.

Comment: This is the flow- 
1: Read the incremental dataset into a df1. 
2: Read the history data for a complete year in df2. 
3: Perform union of df1 and df2 to form df3. 
4. perform dedup using Window function on df3. 
5. write the de-duped dataframe from step4 using partitionBy on hdfs. then copy the split files back to google storage. 

This is what i am trying to achieve. I have now compressed the files using codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec". I am using a n1-highmem-64 cluster for this with 5 nodes. This is a memory intensive job, hence the highmem cluster.

Comment: Also i see that dataproc version 1.2.31 with Hadoop version 2.8.3 takes long time to complete(hours) whereas dataproc image version 1.2.27 Hadoop version 2.8.2 the same job completes in 15 minutes. the repartition is not helping much in the performance.

dedup_df.write.partitionBy("trn_dt").format('csv').mode("overwrite").options(delimiter="|",codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("hdfs_path")

#dedup_df.repartition("trn_dt").write.partitionBy("trn_dt").format('csv').mode("overwrite").options(delimiter="|",codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("hdfs_path")

Comment: Can you try Dataproc 1.2.30 (last version on 2.8.2) -- I wonder whether this is a weird regression in Hadoop itself. That being said, even 15 minutes seems pretty slow to me.

Comment: Just for my sanity, what happens if you use `val dedup_df = spark.range(150000000000L).withColumn("trn_dt", round(rand() * 2300) % 2300)`. If that's slow, then this is an issue with the write. Otherwise, other parts of your code are the issue.

Comment: In general, having a repro with `spark.range` or any other easy-to-generate random data at the right size would be helpful. Also, you may want to bump up `spark.executor.cores`.

Comment: Karthik- Could you explain as to what we are trying to achieve here- val dedup_df = spark.range(150000000000L).withColumn("trn_dt", round(rand() * 2300) % 2300) . I am rolling back to the lower versions and increasing the cores to check if that helps.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to make a dataset that matched your description. `spark.range(N)` gives you a dataframe with elements 1, 2, 3, ..., N. Then, I'm adding the column to partition on (called "trn_dt") with random numbers 0 - 2999 (to match the fact that you have 2300 partitions). I think that should be a good repro to benchmark `write.partitionBy("trn_dt").csv(...)`. Feel free to improve that to match your dataset better.

Comment: 38.23 GiB compressed data on the dataproc 1.2.30 with 13 executors takes an hour to complete. union of the dataframe and doing the dedup on multiple key columns is where the max amount of time is taken.

Comment: Gotcha -- that wasn't obvious to me before. Please update your question to reflect that, and please add a repro.

Comment: Karthik, im pretty new to spark and may end up asking weird questions, but what would you need in a repro ? my code flow and fake data ?

Comment: Yes, please :) If you don't want to share publicly you can also email `dataproc-feedback@google.com`

Comment: Karthik- I have put in the repro as an answer above, since obviously it didnt fit in the comment section. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Another observation, some of the files which have been written to hdfs have a huge number of \\\\(slashes) being appended to the file. not sure how this could have happened

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to the question but the code flow for the existing requirement.

```
col1        col2        col3    col4       col5
asd234qsds  2014-01-02  23.99  2014-01-02  Y
2343fsdf55  2014-01-03  22.56  2014-01-03  Y
123fdfr555  2014-01-04  34.23  2014-01-04  N
2343fsdf5f  2014-01-05  45.33  2014-01-05  N
asd234qsds  2014-01-02  27.99  2014-01-07  Y
```

Please note: the first and the last row have the same keys, but during the Window function only the last row would be considered. My actual data has 51 columns and the Window function is on 9 columns. Im not sure if the compressed data is adding any overhead to this process.

```
lines1 = sc.textFile("gs://incrmental_file.txt*") -- uncompressed data 210KB
part1 = lines1.map(lambda l: l.split("|")) 
df = part1.map(lambda c: Row(col1=c[0],col2=c[1],col3=c[2],col4=c[3], col5 =c[4]))
schema_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
schema_df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
#schema_incr_tbl = spark.sql("""select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from df""") 

lines2 = sc.textFile("gs://hist_files.gz*") -- full year compressed data 38GiB
part2 = lines2.map(lambda l: l.split("|"))
df2 = part2.map(lambda c: Row(col1=c[0],col2=c[1],col3=c[2],col4=c[3], col5 =c[4])) 
schema_df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2)
schema_df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")   

union_fn = schema_hist_tbl.union(schema_incr_tbl)
w = Window.partitionBy("col1","col2").orderBy(col("col4").desc())
union_result = union_fn.withColumn("row_num", 
func.row_number().over(w)).where(col("row_num") == 1).drop("row_num").drop("col4")
union_result.createOrReplaceTempView("merged_tbl") 
schema_merged_tbl = spark.sql("""select col1,col2,col3,col5,col5 as col6 merged_tbl""")
```

schema_merged_tbl.write.partitionBy("col6").format('csv').mode("overwrite").options(delimiter=delim,codec="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").save("hdfs_merge_path")